# Batch file for opening most recent Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware Log

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In Vista, I want to run a batch script to open the most recent file, based either on last modified date, or the date in the filename. It's for Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware logs in the %username&/appdata/roaming/Malwarebytes/Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware/Logs folder.

Log files are in this format here

> mbam-log-2009-03-21 (00-20-21).txt
>
> mbam-log-2009-03-21 (09-42-40).txt
>
> mbam-log-2009-03-21 (11-02-43).txt
>
> mbam-log-2009-03-21 (11-12-01).txt
>
> mbam-log-2009-03-21 (12-01-42).txt
>
> mbam-log-2009-03-21 (12-04-49).txt
>
> mbam-log-2009-03-21 (14-01-41).txt

So its 24-hr format. I read on another page on here, and got this script here..

```
@echo off
dir *.txt /b /on > systext.bak 
FOR /F %%i in (systext.bak) do set sysRunCommand=%%i 
call %sysRunCommand%
del systext.bak /y
```

but it doesn't like the space in the filename.. always get an error.
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have three problems in the script. The first is that %%i is likely to be set to the words with a filename- this can be fixed by using `"delims="` in the `for` statement.

The second is that you need to quote spacey filenames in you `call` statement.

The third is that I'm not aware of a `/y` option for `del`, perhaps you mean `del /f`.

Amyway, give this one a shot:

```
@echo off
dir *.txt /b /on > systext.bak 
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in (systext.bak) do set sysRunCommand=%%i 
call "%sysRunCommand%"
del /f systext.bak
```

Comment: instead of creating a temporary file, you could put the dir command within the for condition like ('dir *.txt /b /on')

Answer (score 0):

The following one-line batch file will open the most recently modified file:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /b /o-d`) do @start "%%i"&goto :eof
```

Using `dir` strikes me as much simpler than trying to dissect the date in the filename. You can also order by filename (as the date format is somewhat ISO-8601-ish is sorts well).

The `goto :eof` is just there to make sure only the most recent file will be opened and not all in order of date/time.

As for your space problem, surrounding the file name with quotes usually should fix that, but sometimes it's a little difficult to know where they have to be. Also, `for` by default tokenizes its input at spaces, that's why I included `delims=` in there which essentially says »Put everything into the variable and don't do any tokenizing«.

Comment: I tried that.

@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /b /o-d`) do @call "%%i" &goto :eof

didnt work. Unless I did it wrong?

Comment: hmm, right, "call" is for calling batch files. My bad. You should really use "start" there, but without the notepad. This should start the text file with whatever application is set for text files on your machine.

Comment: Actually, Windows seems pretty intelligent about that, 'calling' the text file resulted in it being opened by Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, and I don't mean to revive it - I have an alternative approach to the question.

Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware includes the ability to reroute the log file to an alternate location (folder or specified file).

You can run "%programfiles%\malwarebytes' anti-malware\mbam.exe" /logtofile c:\logs\bob-mbam-log.txt. /logtofolder also works. (the above command assumes you're using a 32 bit system.)

When specifying a file, mbam appends instead of overwriting. So, that may make the log a little more difficult to parse.